# Show users that has less than 3 unanswered conversations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to get all users who has less than 3 unanswered conversations with some other conditions.

But for some reason it's not working for me.

**"users" table**

```
| user_id | name | email |
|---------|------|-------|
|  1      |"xxx" |"xxx"  |  
|  2      |"xxx" |"xxx"  |  
|  3      |"xxx" |"xxx"  | 
|  4      |"xxx" |"xxx"  |  
|  5      |"xxx" |"xxx"  |  
|---------|------|-------|
```

**"conversation" table**

```
|   id    | user1| user2 |
|---------|------|-------|
|  1      |  3   |   2   |  
|  2      |  3   |   4   |  
|  3      |  5   |   2   | 
|  4      |  4   |   1   | 
|  5      |  1   |   2   |  
|---------|------|-------|
```

**"message" table**

```
|   id    | conversation | sender | recipient | text |
|---------|--------------|--------|-----------|------|
|   1     |      1       |   3    |     2     |  *** |
|   2     |      2       |   3    |     4     |  *** | 
|   3     |      3       |   5    |     2     |  *** |
|   4     |      4       |   4    |     1     |  *** |
|   5     |      5       |   1    |     2     |  *** |
|   6     |      2       |   4    |     3     |  *** | 
|   7     |      4       |   1    |     4     |  *** |
|---------|--------------|--------|-----------|------|
```

Here is my current query

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id,u.name, u.email 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT *,COUNT(conversation) as totalConversations
        from message 
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING totalConversations IS NULL OR totalConversations < 3
    ) msg ON  (msg.sender = u.id) OR (msg.recipient = u.id)
```

I also try this join

```
LEFT JOIN
    (
       SELECT *,COUNT(id) as totalCoversations
       FROM conversation cn
            INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT conversation,COUNT(ms.conversation) as totalMsg
                    from message ms
                    GROUP BY ms.conversation
                    HAVING totalMsg < 3
            ) msg ON msg.conversation = cn.id
       GROUP BY cn.id
    ) convr ON convr.user2 = u.id
```

Above query must return user 1,4 but not user 2.

Comment: Define _unanswered_.

Comment: Unanswered conversation means: A conversation that has only 1 message that a sender send to recipient but not get reply from recipient.

Comment: First of all you need a sub-query that returns those unanswered conversations. Then you join and group by.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @jarlh can you edit my query in a way that is more easy for me to implement. I'm trying from last 2 days and tried a lot of queries but no luck.

Comment: @MuhammadHafeez how do you know if the sender didnt get reply from recipient ?

Comment: @Moudiz if a conversation has only 1 message that means there is no reply message from recipient. As you can see above tables.

Comment: so as seen from example , all the users didn't reply right ?

Comment: @Moudiz If you see last 2 records in "message" table. The user 1 and 4 has reply.

Comment: @Moudiz look at the 4th record and last record in message table. User 4 has send message to user 1 which belong to conversation id 4. and then in last record user 1 has send message to user 4 within same conversation id 4. Thats means it's reply of from recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to find all conversations that have the same recipient - that means that there was no answer:

```
SELECT conversation, COUNT(DISTINCT recipient) numberOfRecipients, recipient
    from message 
    GROUP BY conversation, recipient 
    HAVING numberOfRecipients = 1
```

Then you count unanswered conversations and group by recipient so you get how much each user has unanswered conversations:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.conversation) totalUnansweredConversations, m.recipient FROM (
    SELECT conversation, COUNT(DISTINCT recipient) numberOfRecipients
    from message 
    GROUP BY conversation
    HAVING numberOfRecipients = 1
  ) t
  JOIN message m ON m.conversation = t.conversation
  GROUP BY m.recipient
  HAVING totalUnansweredConversations < 3
```

Afterward, you just join that derived table with users table and you get users who didn't answer the conversation. Complete query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*
FROM users
JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.conversation) totalUnansweredConversations, m.recipient FROM (
    SELECT conversation, COUNT(DISTINCT recipient) numberOfRecipients
    from message 
    GROUP BY conversation
    HAVING numberOfRecipients = 1
  ) t
  JOIN message m ON m.conversation = t.conversation
  GROUP BY m.recipient
  HAVING totalUnansweredConversations < 3
) derived ON users.id = derived.recipient
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN conversation c ON u.id IN (c.user1,c.user2)
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Tested at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/142506/18).

Comment: I got this error 

'Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'message.recipient' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by'

Comment: I've added ", recipient" to GROUP BY. Try now.

Comment: error is gone but it doesn't return the users who don't have conversations. It should  return null or < 3

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: @MuhammadHafeez I've edited answer with adding UNION. This was a quickfix which is working. I can take some time to refactor it tomorrow if you wish.